# Spring Boot 2.0.0.RELEASE - does not run H2 data.sql

Tags: spring-boot, h2, h2db

Simple Spring Boot application with h2, which has 1 DB table populated via data.sql. Works 100% with spring-boot-starter-parent 1.5.9.RELEASE if I switch to 2.0.0.RELEASE the data.sql is no longer run on startup.

In my pom.xml I have

```
 <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

......

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
     <!-- <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version> -->  
    <version>1.5.9.RELEASE</version>

    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
    </dependency>
     <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>     
        <scope>runtime</scope>       
    </dependency>


</dependencies>

......
```

and an SQL file with inserts into DB table under
src/main/resources/data.sql

In the application.properties file

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:file:~/greeter;AUTO_SERVER=TRUE
spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always

spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
```

**Using 1.5.9.RELEASE on start up in logs you see :**

```
2018-07-23 17:53:41.219  INFO 11404 --- [           main] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : HHH000227: Running hbm2ddl schema export
Hibernate: drop table greeting if exists
Hibernate: create table greeting (id bigint not null, action varchar(255), say varchar(255), primary key (id))
2018-07-23 17:53:41.238  INFO 11404 --- [           main] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : HHH000230: Schema export complete
2018-07-23 17:53:41.341  INFO 11404 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2018-07-23 17:53:41.590  INFO 11404 --- [           main] o.s.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils     : Executing SQL script from URL [file:/..../classes/data.sql]
```

**Using 2.0.0.RELEASE**

Nothing from my application.properties file seems to be picked up. 
The DB is not being dropped/recreated and the data.sql is not imported into the DB. And log is as follows; 
Somehow it seems related to Maven. Startup log where its an issue

```
2018-07-23 21:16:39.532  INFO 3600 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2018-07-23 21:16:39.741  INFO 3600 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2018-07-23 21:16:39.880  INFO 3600 --- [  restartedMain] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2018-07-23 21:16:39.911  INFO 3600 --- [  restartedMain] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: default
    ...]
2018-07-23 21:16:40.114  INFO 3600 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.2.14.Final}
2018-07-23 21:16:40.119  INFO 3600 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
2018-07-23 21:16:40.382  INFO 3600 --- [  restartedMain] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
2018-07-23 21:16:40.685  INFO 3600 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
2018-07-23 21:16:41.840  INFO 3600 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.t.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl  : HHH000476: Executing import script 'org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.ScriptSourceInputNonExistentImpl@542d091e'
2018-07-23 21:16:41.850  INFO 3600 --- [  restartedMain] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2018-07-23 21:16:43.574  INFO 3600 --- [  restartedMain] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter : Looking for @ControllerAdvice: org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@29bb347c: startup date [Mon Jul 23 21:16:33 CAT 2018]; root of context hierarchy
2018-07-23 21:16:43.710  WARN 3600 --- [  restartedMain] aWebConfiguration$JpaWebMvcConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
```

Nothing else but the version changed in pom.xml ...

**What is needed in Spring 2.0.0.RELEASE to get this to run?**

**EDIT 1 EDIT 1 EDIT 1**
Somehow it seems related to Maven dependencies ???????
If I include the repositories in pom.xml such as below all is ok... removing them I have the above mentioned issue

```
<repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
```

Comment: where are you placing your `data.sql` file?

Comment: src/main/resources/data.sql

Comment: can you show me the startup log? I just tried with a simple project and the data.sql seems to have been picked and executed for me...

Comment: @RajaAnbazhagan I edited the question to include startup log for when I am experiencing this issue. Have also added an oddity that seems to correct it.

Comment: Without the repository configuration it runs fine for me... Will you be able to share us a simple reproducible example over GitHub...?

Comment: Also if you don't want any of this but your end result is loading data to your application, try renaming `data.sql` to `import.sql`. hibernate will do the importing for you... This is completely a hibernate feature whereas data.sql is spring feature... Sometimes spring works differently if you define your own data source and stuff...

Answer (score 3):

Make sure that you use *`jdbc:h2:mem:testdb`* as JDBC URL when connecting from h2-console. When we have the default url provided by h2 (`jdbc:h2:~/test`) then you won't see the script result in the database.

Also, to view the debugs on the console, just put `debug=true` in the *application.properties* file.

**In-Memory**

> The URL jdbc:h2:mem:test means open an in-memory database
>   named 'test'. Data is not persisted, and lost when the last connection
>   to the database is closed. Multiple threads can access the same
>   database, but data is only visible within the same process

For more information, see http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html#database_url